# SITE URL REDIRECT WITH DYNAMIC PARAMETERS (Public Access Page)

Tags: force.com-sites, urlhacking, redirect

I'm trying to implement URL Redirect in sites along with dynamic parameters and this is not working.

**Working scenario** : with no dynamic parameter.

Below scenario works fine when this is no dynamic parameter.

[image]

source url :/VFPAGE
Target URL :new-example.com/VFPAGE

Output:

Incoming URL: old-example.com/VFPAGE

Desired destination: new-example.com/VFPAGE

**Ask:**

How to implement below scenario I need to pass the parameter value to destination URL?

Incoming url: old-example.com/VFPAGE?Id=<Dynamic can be different Id's each time>

Desired destination: new-example.com/VFPAGE?Id=<Dynamic can be different Id's each time>

[image]

The above use case is not working, is it possible to implement something like above or do we have a limitation if so can someone please point to documentation ?

Comment: Hi. I think you should [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/323819/edit) your question to add clarity of what you are doing, detail of how you have tried to do it (e.g. screenshots of, or details for, your configuration) and the specific issue you are seeing in your current solution. As it stands I cannot understand what you are getting at.

Comment: Hi Phil sorry for that let me restructure the question. 10 mins please.

Comment: Hi Phil, update the question please let me know in case this is still not clear, I'm trying to implement site url redirect with parameter. I need to pass param value to target URL but I couldn't found any documentation, if param is hardcoded then only it's working.

Comment: Much clearer now.

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_redirects.htm&type=5) "Query parameters in site URL redirects are matched exactly" so there's no way to have these statically defined redirects with dynamic query parameters. You need to leverage your own redirection mechanism instead.

Comment: Thanks a ton Phil for confirmation. I will do my logic in page apex constructor now.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with config.

[Document](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sites_redirects.htm&type=5) clearly states same 'Query parameters in site URL redirects are matched exactly'